# Как добавить лишную строку в TextVIew

Tags: java, android

Хочу добавить одну лишную строчку. Если в TextView указать maxLines = 4.

А после добавить некий текст. То он не появиться так как он уже находится на 5 строчке. Есть ли в TextView метод который бы позволил это сделать.

У меня в TextVIew 10 строчек. Я  хочу отображать 4, когда пользователь нажмет на TextView то TextView раскроется полностью, надо еще добавить слово Read More в конце 4 строчки....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675331/add-view-more-at-the-end-of-textview-after-3-lines

Comment: не знаю, как со строчкой read more, но по остальному все просто: создаете переменную  boolean isExpanded,вешаете setOnClickListener на textView, в методе onclick:  if(!isExpanded) {
            textView.setMaxLines(10);
        }else {
            textView.setMaxLines(4);
        }
        isExpanded=!isExpanded;
    }